# Complex contour integral and measure theory

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, complex-integration

Given $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ a rectificable curve and $f:\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ a continuous function s.t. $\gamma([a,b])\subseteq\Omega$ it is standard to define:
$$\int_{\gamma}f(z)\; dz:=\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\; dt$$
Now I have studied complex measures and I was wandering if this contour integral could be seen in a measure theoretic way, in the same way as you can see standard line integrals in $R^n$ as integrals wrt the Hausdorff measure. In other words I would like to know if exists a complex measure $\mu$ s.t.:
$$\int_{\gamma}f(z)\; dz=\int_\gamma f \; d\mu$$
Unfortunately I could not find anything about this. Can you give me same reference/explaination?

Comment: Given $\gamma$, and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $[a,b]$, you can define the [pushforward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) $\gamma_*(\lambda)(A)=\lambda(\gamma^{-1}(A))$, for all Borel $A\subset \gamma([a,b])$. This gives $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=\int_{\gamma([a,b])}fd\gamma_*(\lambda)$

Comment: @NDB I may be wrong, but it seems this is not the pushforward measure. (Pushforward measure looks like a real valued measure, but obviously we need a complex one in this case). Also, substitute into the formula it seems does not match. $\int_\gamma f(z)dz = \int f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt \neq \int f(\gamma)dt$. I guess may be $\gamma'$ times the pushforward measure.